# How are the steps to create a signed apk different between Eclipse and Android Studio Beta?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, apk, android-keystore

How are the steps to create a signed apk different between Eclipse and Android Studio Beta using these programs? What does a newcomer need to know about this who is moving from Eclipse to Android Studio?

Here are straightforward steps in an apparently older version (this menu item doesn't exist in my version): http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Generating_a_Signed_Release_APK_File_in_Android_Studio#The_Release_Preparation_Process

Can't make a signed app from within v0.8.9.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: All my reading led me to think I had to build a Gradle file!

Comment: if you create the project in Android Studio, then it'll generate one automatically.

Comment: I'm using Cordova PhoneGap to create my app. I used Build > Generate Ant Build... > OK in Android Studio to compile the usual apks (thank you!) But how do we make a signed apk for Google Play in AS?

Comment: I never did that, so I hope someone knows the answer.